# Merging rows containing blank cells and duplicates in Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv

I am looking to merge rows together in a large Excel file using Python Pandas. Let's say, in an Excel or csv file, I have:

```
Kelly | $400 |      |      | $20 |
Kelly |      | $200 |      |     |
Kelly |      |      | $500 |     |
John  |      |  $2  | ($7) |     |
John  |      |      |      | $10 |
```

I want to end up with:

```
Kelly | $400 | $200 | $500 | $20 |
John  |      |  $2  | ($7) | $10 |
```

Is there an easy solution? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for a [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
data={'Name' : ['Kelly', 'Kelly', 'Kelly', 'John', 'John'],
                   'col1' : [400, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
                   'col2' : [np.nan, 200, np.nan, 2, np.nan],
                   'col3' : [np.nan, np.nan, 500, -7, np.nan],
                   'col4' : [20, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 10],})
```

print(df)

```
    Name   col1   col2   col3  col4
0  Kelly  400.0    NaN    NaN  20.0
1  Kelly    NaN  200.0    NaN   NaN
2  Kelly    NaN    NaN  500.0   NaN
3   John    NaN    2.0   -7.0   NaN
4   John    NaN    NaN    NaN  10.0


print(df.groupby('Name').sum())
```

Output:

```
        col1   col2   col3  col4
Name                            
John     0.0    2.0   -7.0  10.0
Kelly  400.0  200.0  500.0  20.0
```

**Edit**: If you're only getting the first column sum, then your data types for the other columns might be non-numeric. If you apply the groupby on the whole dataframe, each column will product the aggfunction result. Try using df.info() to see what data types your columns are.

Comment: the `groupby` method would only return me with the name and the value for the first column. I have tried `df.groupby(["col1", "col2"])["Name"].sum()`; however, this only returned me rows that have both col1 and col2 filled in at the time.